# SQL Server duplicates - Remove values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been going crazy trying to remove duplicate values from my SQL Server database.  One time the query works then it doesn't.  Supposedly this query removed dups, but when querying it did not.  Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BarCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Alias] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [StreetAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ArchiveDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the query I am using to delete the duplicates:

```
WITH CTE([FullName], 
        [BarCode],
        [Alias],
        [StreetAddress],
        [City],
        [State],
        [ZipCode],
      --    [ArchiveDate],   
    DuplicateCount)
AS (SELECT [FullName], 
           [BarCode],
           [Alias],
           [StreetAddress],
           [City],
           [State],
           [ZipCode],
          -- [ArchiveDate],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [FullName], 
                            [BarCode],
                        [Alias],`enter code here`
                        [StreetAddress],
                        [City],
                        [State],
                        [ZipCode]
                        --[ArchiveDate]                           
                                        
           ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM [TelusArchive].[dbo].[Location])
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

It is not deleting the duplicates.  What am I doing wrong..

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Your query deletes duplicates in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a188942a7267d1730c29874c5d1544a7).

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that whatever you might think are duplicates are not.  I would start with the query:

```
SELECT [FullName], [BarCode], [Alias], [StreetAddress], [City], [State], [ZipCode], COUNT(*)
FROM location
GROUP BY [FullName], [BarCode], [Alias], [StreetAddress], [City], [State], [ZipCode]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Based on your question, this should return no rows.

Then, it is unclear where the problem is -- if you really think there are duplicates.

I would suggest removing one column at a time, until you start to get duplicates.  Then you can investigate the values in the column.  A common culprit would be strings that look the same but are not -- say due to spaces or characters that look the same but are different.